# Re-ordenar contenedores con arrastre del ratón

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

tengo una inquietud, desearía hacer lo siguiente, cambiar de posición los `DIV` con solo arrastrar y soltar encima del `DIV` que deseamos intercambiar la posición.

Saludos Chicos.

```css
.caja{
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.caja:nth-child(even){
  background: purple;
}
.caja:nth-child(odd){
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">3</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">4</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">5</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que estás utilizando **JQuery** y estilos de **Bootstrap**, supongo que no te importará añadir *[JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/)*.

A mi parecer añade lo que requieres: la función [sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), que incluye la funcionalidad de reordenar y mantener la posición de los contenedores dentro de un objeto `<div>`.

Además del código, te dejo aquí también el [ejemplo oficial.](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Por cierto, he tenido que cambiar la versión slim de la librería JQuery por su versión completa, ya que la primera no tiene ***sortable***.

```css
.caja{
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.caja:nth-child(even){
  background: purple;
}
.caja:nth-child(odd){
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<head>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".row").sortable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">3</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">4</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">5</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 caja">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```